# Using .lib and .dll files in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dll, g++

I have to make a project to run successfully on a Linux machine. Right now my project works very well on windows machine. On Windows machine it is compiling and working fine. My project is using one ".lib" and one ".dll" file to do the tasks successfully on Windows. Can i use the same .lib file and .dll  file on linux machine to build the project successfully? I am compiling the project with G++ and using GNU Makefile to do the task.

What should i do in the case that i can not use the .LIB and .DLL file on Linux machine.

Answer (score 8):

The best thing would be to get the DLL compiled on Linux as a .so and use that instead. Linux does not need the equivalent of a .lib to access shared objects.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look at the [Wine](http://www.winehq.org) project, which allows you to port Windows programs to Linux (and other Unixes) generally without code modification

The Wine project has a toolkit that allows you to take your existing Windows source and compile it to work on Linux, linking against winelib